# Como pegar uma lista de divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quero criar uma espécie de lista de `divs`, onde quando eu aperto o botão, eu mostro uma `div` específica enquanto que as outras ficam ocultas, tipo um `carrosel` de `div`.

```
 <section class="carrosel">
        <div class="passar"> 
            <button type="button" id="voltar-img" onclick="voltar()"><</button>
        </div>

        <div class="maleta">


            <div class="projetos" id="calculadora-imc">
                <img class="img-project" src="../ícone/calculadora.png" alt="">
                <p class="nome-projetos">CALCULADORA DE IMC</p>
                <a class="link-project" href="" target="blank">Acessar Projeto</a>
            </div>

            <div class="projetos" id="restaurante-on">
                <img class="img-project" src="../ícone/restaurante.png" alt="">
                <p class="nome-projetos">CARDÁPIO ONLINE</p>
                <a class="link-project" href="" target="blank">Acessar Projeto</a>
            </div>

        </div>

        
        <div class="passar">
            <button class="passar-img" type="button" onclick="passar()">></button>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score -2):

você pode usar o componente [dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) do bootstrap para fazer isso.

1. Adicione o bootstrap em seu projeto

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

2. adicione a classe "dropdown-item" em suas divs